# Sending parameters through ssh. Are there NON-BLOCKING input functions?

Tags: c++, ssh

I am working with an embedded system in which a Linux-based OS is running. Let's say that an application is running and the behavior needs to change when some actions happen. I did it using buttons and switches on the board but I have no idea on how to do it via ssh where the output of the application is constantly prompt. Any suggestion? Is it possible to use the keyboard of the laptop to send parameters at runtime only if a keyboard-button is pressed? (let's imagine I want to press only the `+` and the `-`). Of course, the output of the application should continue to be prompt constantly.

Of course the solution `cin <<` will not work because it stops the execution until the new parameter is set up. The aim should be "change behavior if and only if `+` or `-` are pressed".

Comment: If I understand you correct this is a terminal issue. You have to put your terminal into character mode, so each character is transmitted immediately, and not only on "enter"

Comment: Not exactly (I will update the question). The terminal will continue to prompt the output message of the application. At some point I decide to press `+` and the embedded system will change some of the parameters. If I press the `+` it changes the parameter but, if I press nothing, it continues to do its jobs with the old parameters it has.

Answer (score 0):

Use signals. [Register a signal handler](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code) in your program and signal it from the outside with `pkill -<SIGNAL> -f <PROGRAM>` or `kill -<SIGNAL> <PID>`. For instance:

```
ssh user@server pkill -USR1 -f my_program
```